# Testing Rails model validations with RSpec, without testing AR itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

## Testing Rails model validations with RSpec, without testing AR itself

Lets as setup we have model `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, on: :create
  validate :password, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-z]*\z/ }
end
```

A see several ways to test this:

```
it { expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:name).on(:create) }
```

or

```
it do
  user = User.create(name: '')

  expect(user.errors[:name]).to be_present
end
```

#### My main question is which of the approaches is better and why?  Can suggest me different approach?

Additional questions:

- How much should I test? As an example, I can write so many tests for the regex, but it will be hell for maintenance.
- How much you think will be full test coverage in this example?

Comment: Just FYI, the `validate_presence_of` matcher is not built-in to RSpec, it's added by the shoulda-matchers gem: https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: the first is more compact so better, it implies the functionality of the second approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionalities of:

- Rails being able to validate the presence of an arbitrary value on your model
- `errors` being added to an object for an attribute that is missing when a validation for it is configured

are covered in the tests for Rails itself (specifically, in the [ActiveModel tests](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/test/cases/validations/presence_validation_test.rb#L15)).

That leaves needing to write the tests for the *config* that covers the business logic of *your* app eg validating the presence of the *specific* `name` attribute on your *specific* `User` class etc.  In my opinion, the matchers from the [shoulda-matchers gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) should have you covered:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  subject(:user) { build(:user) } # assuming you're using FactoryGirl

  describe 'validations' do
    specify 'for name' do
      expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:name).on(:create)
      # NOTE: saving here is needed to test uniqueness amongst users in
      # the database
      user.save
      expect(user).to validate_uniqueness_of(:name)
    end

    specify 'for password' do
      expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:password)
      expect(user).to allow_value('abcd').for(:password)
      expect(user).to_not allow_value('1234').for(:password)
    end
  end
end
```

I think that unless you have specific custom error messages for your errors that you want to test for (ie you've overridden the default Rails ones), then tests like `expect(user.errors[:name]).to be_present` can be removed (even if you have custom errors, I still think they're of dubious value since those messages will become locale-dependent if you internationalise your app, so I'd test for the display of some kind of error on the `page` in a feature spec instead).

> I can write so many tests for the regex, but it will be hell for maintenance.

I don't think you can really get around this when testing validations for `format`, so I'd suggest just write some representative test cases and then add/remove those cases as you discover any issues you may have missed, for example:

```
# use a `let` or extract out into a test helper method
let(:valid_passwords) do
  ['abcd', 'ABCD', 'AbCd'] # etc etc
end

describe 'validations' do
  specify 'for password' do
    valid_passwords.each do |password|
      expect(user).to allow_value(password).for(:password)
    end
  end
end
```

> How much you think will be full test coverage in this example?

I've gotten 100% code coverage from reports like [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) when writing unit specs as described above.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 of them should be used, because:

```
it { expect(user).to validate_presence_of(:name).on(:create) }
```

=> You are expecting the `validate_presence_of` should be run on `create`, this should be the test case for model

```
it do
  user = User.create(name: '')
  expect(user.errors[:name]).to be_present
end
```

=> You are expecting a side effect when creating user with your input, so this should be the test case for controller

Why you shouldn't remove 1 of them:

- Remove the 1st test case: what happens if you do database validation level instead, you expect an active record level validation
- Remove the 2nd test case: what happens on controller actually creates a new `User`, how do you expect the error returning!

Comment: So you suggest second test case to be controller unit test? So you prefer first one for model unit test?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm thinking and used in my current project, we usually test behavior (call what) and test side effect (happens what)!